# Update application state when using "onMessageOpenedApp" firebase messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Flutter application must update the user's screen automatically when receiving a push notification, in this case I use Flutter bloc and upon receiving the notification, I emit an event so that the state changes and so with a blocBuilder I change the state, however I have a problem that when I have the application in the background, when I open it again by clicking directly on the icon and not on the notification, this screen does not update, it is as if no change was made.

This is how I have it configured:

```
static Future<void> firebaseMessagingSetup() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('TOKEN: ${await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()}');
    }
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
  }
```

In my main file I have it declared:

`FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseHandlingBackgroundMessage);`

`Future<void> firebaseHandlingBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async { await Firebase.initializeApp(); }`